# Displaying fields dependent on SQL values in Rails Views

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, view

was wondering if anyone can help me. 
I'm just starting ou so this may seem a bit mundane to some people. I 
have a view which I need to display certain fields if a particular 
value is selected in the database. 
The example is similar to a blog post where you may or may not want to 
show a source link. So in the backend there is a tick box which is 
attached to a sql boolean value then if that is ticked you can also 
put the link in for the source location. 
On the front end however if the boolean is set to false  I don't want 
to display the data in that field. What's the best way of going about 
this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditionals in erb views.

For example:

```
<% if @v == 4 %>
   <p>v is equal 4.</p>
<% else %>
   <p>v isn't equal 4.</p>
<% end %>
```